# C++ convert vector containing objects to vector containing doubles

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector containing objects:

```
std::vector<myObjectType> myObjectVector;
```

`myObjectType` contains a double member variable called `value`, which I can retrieve in two ways:

```
myObjectType aObject;
double aObjectDouble = aObject(); // possibility 1 (overloaded operator)
double aObjectDouble = aObject.get_value(); // possibility 2
```

Now I can convert the `std::vector<myObjectType> myObjectVector` into `std::vector<double> myObjectVectorDoubles`, where the `std::vector<double>` contains the double values of each object as follows:

```
std::vector<double> myObjectVectorDoubles;
myObjectVectorDoubles.push_back(myObjectVector[0].get_value());
myObjectVectorDoubles.push_back(myObjectVector[1].get_value());
...
...
```

or simply this way

```
std::vector<double> myObjectVectorDoubles;
myObjectVectorDoubles.push_back(myObjectVector[0]());
myObjectVectorDoubles.push_back(myObjectVector[1]());
...
...
```

I can put this in a for loop, but is this the cleanest (or most efficient) solution?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Comment: although, I really don't get why not to use a loop?

Comment: A loop seems the most readable way and, likely, has the highest performance if `vector::reserve()` is called in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `std::transform`. For example if you have a `class`

```
class Foo {
  double val;
public:
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(double const val_) : val(val_) {}
  double getVal() const { return val; }
};
```

In your program do:

```
std::vector<Foo> v {{1.2}, {2.3}, {5.6}};  
std::vector<double> dv(v.size());
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), dv.begin(), [](auto const &f) { return f.getVal(); });
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/420b33e15cd9dae5)

If your compiler doesn't support C++14 generic lambdas change to:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), dv.begin(), [](Foo const &f) { return f.getVal(); });
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the warning: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration and the error: invalid use of ‘auto’ with this code, do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: @Pietair probably your compiler doesn't support C++14, look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but with your objects:

```
std::vector<int> ivec({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
std::vector<double> dvec;
for(auto&& x : ivec)
    dvec.push_back(double(x));
```

So in your case:

```
std::vector<myObjectType> myObjectVector {...}
std::vector<double> myDoubleVector;
for(auto&& x : myObjectVector)
        myDoubleVector.push_back(x.get_value());
```

Comment: OP knows it can be done with a loop, that's not in question.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ At least it's clear and easy to read, and possibly most efficient. Don't torture people with complicated standard library algorithms, if they don't know how these work. It's worst thing to do - to use things you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not exactly what you asked for but I did a little experiment myself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    double value;

    Foo(double v) :
        value{ v } {}

    operator double() {
        return value;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<Foo> foos{ 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0 };
    for(double d : foos) {
        std::cout << d << ", ";
    }
}
```

And it worked.
I don't know your situation but as I've shown above you might not even need to convert your vector of objects to a vector of doubles.

Comment: But he wants a vector

Comment: @Bob__ Yes I understand. I am merely posting this as an alternative solution to whatever problem the OP is having. But yes, I don't know what the OP is actually trying to achieve so this might not be useful at all to him... or maybe it is useful. I'll let him decide.